# Absolute String in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

How do I turn a Whole `String` into Absolute String Variable like turning All Special Characters, HTML tags, Links, Codes, and any other stuff that the user can insert into a textarea. I'm currently making a Mail System that would Accept any form of Input from the user, Like `Yahoo Mail` it Accepts anything that you throw at it (I think).

It will insert the `Contents` of the string into Mysql database, I already used `mysql_real_escape_string` for Special Characters and such, How about other tags and Links?

This is the `Content` that I copy in `Yahoo Mail` and my `Mail System`:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

I tried to copy that whole content of the site because I just want to know if My Mail System will accept JS, Jquery, Css, Html, Php, and Other Language as `String`.

> My Problem wasn't on converting Special Character and such, it was on the Mysql. The Field that contains Message only has a type: `text` and so it can't support Long Text like the Link here.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) should help with what you're trying to do.

```
$content = strip_tags($input);
```

Comment: if I use this that would make other Tags unusable, and I don't want that.

Comment: It has an optional parameter to pass tags that you'd still like to allow.

Answer (score 0):

See [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to understand what you're asking, but I think you want to have a textarea that you can add rich text to, similar to a web-based mail program. If I understand what you're wanting to do correctly, I would look into a javascript library which will take a normal textarea and turn it into a cute little WYSIWYG editor.  Two common ones:

- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.com)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com)

Comment: Im currently using CKEditor for my textarea, and I want those contents to be saved into MYsql database.